# SQL QUERY to change values

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to update my table to change values between column 2 and column 3 whenever column 3 not equal -1. So the row wont be changed if column 3 = -1 else it will shift values between column 2 and 3.

this is a sample table.

[image: لالا]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Case` statement

```
SELECT RowID,
       Col1,
       Case WHEN Col3 = -1 THEN Col3 ELSE Col2 END AS Col
FROM table
```

Comment: Thanks that was very helpful>